# How do i create a custom post query when the meta value is an array?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, query-posts, meta-query

A number of properties have been imported from an external API and saved into a custom post type called 'Properties'.

I want to filter these properties by the **city** they are located in, however it is not as simple as just having a meta key and value I can query.

I have attached an image below of the _addresses key and you can see the value is a nested array and its in here that city is located:
[image: Screenshot of the custom post meta details]

The query I was using is the following with the value missing, I don't think I can just out the city in here, I've tried and it does not work (note I have blanked out the values for confidentiality):

```
$meta_query[] = [
    'key' => '_addresses',
    'value' => **what goes here?**,
    'compare' => 'in',
];
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Annoyingly... the WP_Query meta query can only read the value as a bool, string or integer. If the value is anything but bool, string or integer... then its game over. A solution would be to attribute these values to custom fields directly related to each post so you can filter them. Otherwise its impossible.

Comment: Also your screenshot shows values as php `array()`. I am guessing output you've shown must be `json_decoded` data from a mysql cell? This is not native Wordpress screenshots you've shown, what plugin are you using to show this `post_meta` data?

Comment: Hi @joshmoto, yes you are correct it is using a plugin called  JSM's Show Post Metadata to quickly see the metadata when editing posts